# Inverting a key to values mapping

Tags: scala, dictionary

Lets say I have a set of a class `Action` like this: `actions: Set[Action]`, and each `Action` class has a `val consequences : Set[Consequence]`, where `Consequence` is a case class.

I wish to get a map from `Consequence` to `Set[Action]` to determine which actions cause a specific `Consequence`. Obviously since an `Action` can have multiple `Consequence`s it can appear in multiple sets in the map.

I have been trying to get my head around this (I am new to Scala), wondering if I can do it with something like map() and groupBy(), but a bit lost. I don't wish to revert to imperative programming, especially if there is some Scala mapping function that can help.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `MultiMap` is a trait you mix into a `mutable.Map[A, Set[B]]` that adds an `addBinding(a: A, b: B)` method which accumulates any number of distinct `B` into a single key. It also adds an `entryExists` method that lets you inquire as to the presence of any single `B` within the set associated with a given key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly elegant because `groupBy` doesn't handle the case of operating already on a `Tuple2`, so you end up doing a lot of tupling and untupling:

```
case class Conseq()
case class Action(conseqs: Set[Conseq])

def gimme(actions: Seq[Action]): Map[Conseq, Set[Action]] = 
  actions.flatMap(a => a.conseqs.map(_ -> a))
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2)(collection.breakOut))
```

The first line "zips" each action with all of its consequences, yielding a `Seq[(Conseq, Action)]`, grouping this by the first product element gives `Map[Conseq, Seq[(Conseq, Action)]`. So the last step needs to transform the map's values from `Seq[(Conseq, Action)]` to a `Set[Action]`. This can be done with `mapValues`. Without the explicit builder factory, it would produce a `Seq[Action]`, so one would have to write `.mapValues(_.map(_._2)).toSet`. Passing in `collection.breakOut` in the second parameter list to `map` makes it possible to save one step and make `map` directly produce the `Set` collection type.

---

Another possibility is to use nested folds:

```
def gimme2(actions: Seq[Action]) = (Map.empty[Conseq, Set[Action]] /: actions) {
  (m, a) => (m /: a.conseqs) {
    (m1, c) => m1.updated(c, m1.getOrElse(c, Set.empty) + a)
  }
}
```

This is perhaps more readable. We start with an empty result map, traverse the actions, and in the inner fold traverse each action's consequences which get merged into the result map.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining a little what's happening at each line? Especially the last line.